# Creating matrix of colnumbers from a vector

Tags: r, vector, matrix

Let's say, I have a vector of size 10.  How do I create a matrix with position of vector elements arranged like this.

```
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
     2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10     1
     3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    1     2
     4    5    6    7    8    9   10    1    2     3
     5    6    7    8    9   10    1    2    3     4
     6    7    8    9   10    1    2    3    4     5
     7    8    9   10    1    2    3    4    5     6
     8    9   10    1    2    3    4    5    6     7
     9   10    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8
    10    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

```
x = 1:10
matrix(x, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(x) + 1, byrow = T)[, -(length(x) + 1)]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10     1
# [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    1     2
# [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    1    2     3
# [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10    1    2    3     4
# [6,]    6    7    8    9   10    1    2    3    4     5
# [7,]    7    8    9   10    1    2    3    4    5     6
# [8,]    8    9   10    1    2    3    4    5    6     7
# [9,]    9   10    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8
#[10,]   10    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
```

As @flodel noted in the comments, you could, also, build the matrix with an extra row and remove it. And, also, use nicer format: `head(matrix(x, nrow = length(x) + 1 , ncol = length(x)), -1)`.

Comment: +1 - a shorter form would be `head(matrix(x, nrow = length(x)+1 , ncol = length(x)), -1)`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
sapply(1:10, function(idx){ 
 vec <- 1:10
 if(idx != 1){
  vec <- c(vec[idx:10], 1:(idx-1))
 }
 vec
 }
)
```